# Remove remaining string after / character javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been working with strings lately and I'm wondering how to go about solving how to remove remaining string after first / character.

```
this/is/my/string
```

Expected output:

```
This
```

My code:

```
string = string.slice(0, string.indexOf('/'));
result = string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
```

What I'm getting is `Thi`... What am I doing wrong here? Remove after first / and capitalize doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: Tested this in `node`, I get `'This'`...

Comment: Tested in browser console it returns `This`

Comment: The code doesn't produce the output you say it does.

Comment: Are you placing that text in some DOM element in which it does not fit and hence it gets truncated (*`overflow:hidden` for example*) ?

Comment: Be aware your code assumes `string` won't begin with `/`. You can simplify it to `string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1, string.indexOf('/'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you already have above actually worked for me.
See: http://jsbin.com/vozecenufi/1/edit?js,console

But, this approach may be cleaner:

```
var s = 'this/is/my/string';
var result = s.split('/')[0];

// now capitalize first letter
result = result.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + result.substring(1);

console.log(result); // prints "This"
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/puwabubaza/edit?js,console

Comment: Believe OP wants the first letter to be capitalized, hence the `toUpperCase`. That being said, I just ran OP's code in a separate window and the output was `This` just as expected.

Comment: @Santi gotcha, I updated my answer to show the up-casing

Comment: Definitely much cleaner and it works for me (really not sure why it wasn't in the first place). Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the string is defined!

```js
var string = 'This/is/test'

string = string.slice(0, string.indexOf('/'));
var result = string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why would the output be `Thi` if the string was not defined?

Comment: If OP's issue was that the string wasn't defined, why would it return `Thi` instead of `This`? I believe, while OP did leave out the definition, it's to be assumed that it is above.